# How to declare a constant array in class with constant class variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, variables, constants

How to declare a constant array in class with constant class variable? Is it possible.
I don't want dynamic array.

I mean something like this:

```
class test
{
    const int size;
    int array[size];
    public:
    test():size(50)
    {}
}

int main()
{
    test t(500);
    return 0;
}
```

the above code gives errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible: As long as `size` is a dynamic variable, `array[size]` cannot possibly be implemented as a static array.

If you like, think about it this way: `sizeof(test)` must be known at compile time (e.g. consider arrays of `test`). But `sizeof(test) == sizeof(int) * (1 + size)` in your hypothetical example, which isn't a compile-time known value!

You can make `size` into a template parameter; that's about the only solution:

```
template <unsigned int N>
class Test
{
  int array[N];
  static const unsigned int size = N; // unnecessary really
public:
  // ...
};
```

Usage: `Test<50> x;`

Note that now we have `sizeof(Test<N>) == sizeof(int) * (1 + N)`, which *is* in fact a compile-time known value, because for each `N`, `Test<N>` is a *distinct* type.

Comment: Isn't this just a template version of the class specific static integer constant approach?

Comment: @Als: well, yes, in as far as the "class-specific static integer" can now be specified by the author via the template parameter.

Comment: @Als: If you mean, this and your answer is almost same, then no. You can have `Test<10>`, `Test<20>`, `Test<30>` and so on, but in your case, the size is fixed: you can have only `array[size]` and `size` is fixed at `50`.

Comment: @Nawaz: Please spare me the interference of flaring this in to something which it is not.This is not about who's answer is better as you are trying to make it in to.

Comment: @Als: What part of my comment do you disagree with?

Comment: @Nawaz: I disagree your commenting to me in the first place.I think Kerrek and Me are mature enough to discuss something man to man, without someone to referee.And my previous comment already told you what I disagree with so please go away.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Its a neat piece of hack over the over the in class static int,I love it, Much better than my answer.I will delete mine for your solution is better.

Comment: @Als: I don't think it hurts to have several different suggestions around! Now I feel bad ... and after all, all I did was copy the idea of `std::array`! :-S (I do prefer static constants over enums, though. I'm not sure where the enum trick comes from; static constants seem to be far more semantically "right". Maybe they didn't use to be implemented correctly by compilers?)

Comment: @KerrekSB:I would let my answer stay but this answer does all that my answer provides plus an additional killer flexibility.As for the `enum-hack` approach. Both of those approaches are documented in Scott Meyers book If I remember correctly.

Comment: @Als: This is a public forum. Your dislikes or likes cannot stop me (or anyone) from commenting what I (or they) think is right. Also, as for your being "mature", no comment on that.

Comment: I thought the enum hack was purely for compilers that didn't yet support using a static const class constant to define the size of a non-static class member. I suspect that it is much less useful now.

Comment: @Nawaz: Move on & stop being a paparazzi, You are already told your refereeing and implicit attempt to flair a war is not needed(atleast for me and in this situation).I don't expect someone like you to know the meaning of maturity really so that's fine.

Comment: @Als: "war"? You must be kidding. I commented what I think is right. That was not anything personal, not even remotely. But it seems you took it that way, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You mean a fixed sized array? You could use `std::array` like this:

```
#include <array>

class test
{
    static const size_t s_size = 50;
    std::array<int, s_size>   m_array;
public:
    test()
    {
    }
};
```

Or if you want to support different sizes you need to resort to a class template like this:

```
#include <array>

template <size_t SIZE>
class test
{
    std::array<int, SIZE>   m_array;
public:
    test()
    {
    }
};
```

`std:array` has the added benefit of keeping the size information along with the member (unlike arrays which decay to pointers) and is compatible with the standard library algorithms.

There is also a version that Boost offers ([boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/array.html)) which is similar.

Comment: I want to use a constant class variable instead of 50. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Only if it is a compile time constant. Updated code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code yields an error because compiler needs to know the size of data type of each member. When you write `int arr[N]` type of member `arr` is "an array of N integers" where `N` must be known number in compile time.

One solution is using enum:

```
class test
{
    enum 
    {
        size = 50
    };

    int arr[size];
   public:
    test() {}
};
```

Another is declaring size as static const member of class:

```
class test
{
    static const int size = 50; 
    int arr[size];
   public:
    test(){}
};
```

Note that in-class initialization is allowed only for static class integers! For other types you need to initialize them in code file.